# RDS is quickly running out of storage, how can I debug this?

Tags: postgresql

I am using RDS and  looking at my POSTGRES size via \l+ and I see that it is using 154 GB hard disk space.  However, when I look at my StorageSpace statistic in RDS, it says that I’m using: 210GB.  I am trying to figure out where the 56GB that are unaccounted for, are coming from?  I found that 16GB of this is Log Files.  Can it be pglogical and my WAL taking up a lot of space (I recently learned that the sync is not replicating at the moment). Any other ideas of what it can be?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that one of my replication ‘subscriptions’ was broken on a Subscriber database.  Once, I fixed the subscription, pglogical started replicating successfully, and my storage went up 40GB instantly.